Derivative of a function with respect to a function for single variable
I feel like this is something obvious that I should know but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it.
We know that a derivative of a function can be taken the following way:
$$\frac{df(g(x))}{dg(x)} = \frac{df(x)}{dx}\frac{x}{g(x)}.$$
But when we have $$f = f(g(x), h(x)),$$ $${df} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial g(x)}dg + \frac{\partial f}{\partial h(x)}dh = \frac{df(x)}{dx}\frac{dx}{dg}dg + \frac{df(x)}{dx}\frac{dx}{dh}dh = 2df$$
So, why is it that $${df} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial g(x)}dg + \frac{\partial f}{\partial h(x)}dh$$ does not hold?
We know that if $f = f(x,y),$ $df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$ is true. And if $f = f(g(x), g(y))$ Leibniz rule also holds. So why does the Leibniz rule not hold for single variable case?

Why do you freely interchange partial derivatives and a differential? Do you understand how different the natures of those operators are?
